# Passing unevaluated expression to substitute + eval combo

Tags: r, substitution

I am trying to pass an expression that should be evaluated with respect to the data frame, essentially mirroring the `subset()`. The issue is, I need to be able to have it inside other functions.

This essentially means preserving the expression and not evaluating it until the time is right (i.e., the subset-like function is called).

The way I was able to finally succeed is by passing `env` with a default value `sys.frame(sys.nframe())` which should evaluate to the function's frame. The disadvantage is that this needs to be parameter of every outer function to preserve the nesting property:

```
f1 = function(x, expr, env=sys.frame(sys.nframe())){
    expr = substitute(expr, env)
    eval(expr, x)
    }

f2 = function(x, expr, env=sys.frame(sys.nframe())){
    f1(x, expr, env)
    }

f3 = function(x, expr, env=sys.frame(sys.nframe())){
    f2(x, expr, env)
    }

f4 = function(x, expr){
    f2(x, expr) # no env passing
    }

m = head(mtcars, 2) # less typing

f1(m, mpg > 20) # TRUE TRUE -- expected
f2(m, mpg > 20) # TRUE TRUE -- yaay
f3(m, mpg > 20) # TRUE TRUE -- yaay
f4(m, mpg > 20) # expr      -- naay :(
```

Can I rewrite `f1` so it would automatically unwind the call-stack and find the correct `env` to substitute the passed expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build the calls with `do.call()`. For example

```
f1 = function(x, expr){
  expr = substitute(expr)
  eval(expr, x)
}

f2 = function(x, expr){
  do.call("f1", list(x, substitute(expr)))
}

f3 = function(x, expr){
  do.call("f2", list(x, substitute(expr)))
}
f1(m, mpg > 20) 
# [1] TRUE TRUE
f2(m, mpg > 20) 
# [1] TRUE TRUE
f3(m, mpg > 20) 
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```

But in general I would strongly recommend against this. Normally you would have a user facing function that will deal with the non-standard evaulation and then you would just pass along a quoted language string or, in the cause of the rlang/tidyverse world, a quosure that you can evaluate later. Relying on nested non-standard evaluation calls usually just leads to more headaches when trying to programmatically use the functions.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I did encounter `do.call` before, but only as a part of the solution, not as _the_ solution when searching for similar answers here. Can you please provide an explanation? For instance, the help from `do.call` (which I haven't never read until the end) suggest that this might be undefined behaviour.

"*The behavior of some functions, such as ‘substitute’, will not be
     the same for functions evaluated using ‘do.call’ as if they were
     evaluated from the interpreter.  The precise semantics are
     currently undefined and subject to change.*"

Comment: I am aware that non-standard evaluation should be avoided, it was a headache when trying to make it work. But it does save on code duplication. If you could please provide alternative solutions (I am only interested in base)

Comment: The note in the help page is about trying to call `do.call("substitute", ...)` which does not apply to this scenario. In base R you would have one function that takes care of non-standard evaluation and captures the expression, then all your other functions expect a quoted expression. So if you have functions `f1 <- function(x, nse) {f2(x, substitute(nse))}; f2 <- function(x, expr) {eval(expr, x)}` The different syntax to call them is `f1(m, mpg > 20); f2(m, quote(mpg > 20))`. If you have the explicit quoted expression it's much easier to program with.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just woke up and realized the `do.call("substitute", ...)` only after I wrote it when I was in the shower.